Confusing logistic regression model output
I'm analyzing data from a national dataset with a large sample size (>88,000) using a weighted logistic regression model to predict the odds of having the outcome based on various group membership statuses. I want to look at each of the group memberships in comparison to not being a member of that group rather than in comparison to a defined reference group (e.g., adding all the dummy coded variables rather than leaving out the reference variable). This worked fine for most of the health outcomes I looked at, but one of them is returning results where being a member of every one of the exhaustive and mutually exclusive groups has an OR of >1 with CI that do not cross zero. Which I interpret to mean that each group has elevated odds compared to not being a member of that group... which makes no logical sense.
I'm using SAS 9.4 surveylogistic procedure with NOMCAR specified to account for missing data. The domain, weights, strata, cluster, and model have been triple checked for accuracy and look good. All the cell sizes are above 10. The model converges with no errors. All of the output looks reasonable and relatively close to the results of the unweighted analysis I ran as part of the diagnostic when I saw the results of the weighted analysis, though one of the groups was not significant on the unweighted analysis (unweighted OR 1.06; weighted OR 1.80, CI 1.11-2.9)
I'm trying to decide if the issue is that doing the comparison without a specified reference group (I would expect a ridging error if so, and none occurred) or if the weighting in the model was able to shift things somehow to this odd outcome. Or conversely, if there is something wrong with my interpretation and the output is fine. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Did you fit an overall intercept alongside the full set of dummies? If not, there's your explanation: the parameters are not a difference between groups but against the null linear predictor ($\mu=0.5$). If you did then your model isn't of full rank and possibly not very meaningful (it sounds like you penalized it so the dummies might be competing with the intercept?).

How did you look at each group in comparison to all the others? Did you change this to a series of binary questions? Although coding questions are off topic here it might help to show your PROC SRUVEYLOGISTIC code
